# we unable to find the transaction

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a application iconnect,iconnect( Receiver ) application is expecting the message from the RTGS(Sender) application,RTGS is transferred the around 40000 messages. iconnect application is received the all messages except one messages. we have checked with RTGS application for the same,they have successfully sent the messages to targeted queue.
{ 1)We have checked all channel status its working fine, 
2)We have checked the xmit queue and local queue curdepth.no messages are pilled up in queue.
3)We have checked the uncom messages in queue level no uncom messages are available.
4)And also we have checked application logs and DB logs,we haven't found the transaction. }
we unable to find the one transaction can any one help me for why the transaction got failed.and where we can find the failed transactions transactions.

@Subbarao: thanks for replay we have already tried the below command getting popup "no transaction found"
dspmqtrn -m queue manager name.

is there any process to we can find the losses transaction.

Comment: Dspmqtrn command can be used to get failed transactions

Comment: Did the message expire or do you find it in the Dead letter queue ?